# Is there a way to send a message bak to a lambda that invokes a Fargate task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Hello and thanks for taking time to look at my question.

I see that its possible to pass a token from a lambda step function to a Fargate task and the token can be accessed in the running Docker container, when using .waitForTaskToken to a Task state’s resource and that token can be passed bak to the step function when the task has run..

I have a lambda function that invokes a Fargate task. But I am finding hard to know when the node script I am running in the Docker container has completed or succeeded /failed. I'd like to be able to send a success or error 'message' back to the lambda when the script has run. Is this possible using a similar approach to the tokens used in step functions?

Does anyone know how I might do that or where I can find out.

Thanks for any comments

Comment: There's no way to send a message back to a Lambda function like that, and most likely the Lambda function instance has finished execution by then anyway. Are you actually using step functions here, or are you just using step functions as an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I had seen step functions and get your point, I wanted to avoid them (fear of the new etc), but if that is what has to be done then it looks like a well documented approach I can follow.. Thank you for your response and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options that I can think of:

- You can use the AWS SDK of your choice [(or AWS CLI) to poke back the Lambda directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-awscli.html) (whether that's the same lambda or another one it's up to you).
- Similarly you can use [SNS Fanout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda-as-subscriber.html) and send the status to an SNS topic (to which you subscribe the Lambda function that you want to start)
- You can send the status to [CloudWatch Events (AmazonEvent Bridge) which could trigger your Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)
- You can send your container logs to Cloudwatch Logs and [subscribe your Lambda to the respective Log Group.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample)

And an [example with SF, SNS and Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-container-task-notification.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer just the stuff I neded. Many thanks for your time.